# Linked List Manual Sort

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm having a really difficult time solving this problem.  I have spent hours on it and can't figure it out.

I have a linked list that I am trying to manually sort.  My nodes are called CNodes.  There is a start CNode, a tail CNode and a newNext CNode.

Each Node contains a contact.   The contact has a firstname that I am trying to sort the list by.

I know there are more automatic ways to do this, but I need to demonstrate that I understand how to sort (which clearly I do not at this point).

I am trying to do this by iterating over each node and comparing it to start, then changing the start entity if it qualifies.

This code is not working...I've been working on it for two days and am really stuck.

Any specific suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
CNode nextNode=start;
while(nextNode.getNext()!=null) {
    CNode newNext;
    tail=nextNode;
    while(tail!=null) {
        if(start.getContact().getStrFirstName().compareTo(tail.getContact().getStrFirstName()) > 0) {
            //We put the starting node in a temp node
            newNext=start;
            newNext.setNext(tail.getNext());


            //We set our current node to the start
            start=tail;
            start.setNext(newNext);

            //Set the next node of start to the original next one of the one we
            //just removed from the chain

            //Set current marker to the new first nodes' next entity
            tail=start.getNext();
            //Set the next node for the marker to the one we just removed

        } else {
            tail=tail.getNext();
        }

    }
    nextNode=nextNode.getNext();                 
}
```

Comment: Before trying to code this, test your proposed algorithm by sorting cards using it.

Comment: first be clear on algorithm...what is it and why should it work

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is start with an array, and get the sorting concept down. You also need to figure out what type of sort you are going to do, you're currently trying to do a bubble sort. There is also a merge sort, quick sort, and others. Once you pick the type of sort you want, you can then do it on an array, then move to node.

Here are some sorts:

- https://github.com/BlaineOmega/MergeSort Bubble    sort:
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort Quick sort:
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 0):

So what you're doing is a bubble sort. For a visual representation of what the is, look at this (from Wikipedia): http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Bubble-sort-example-300px.gif

So in the while loop, when two nodes need to be switched, we're going to store the 'next' (current) node into a temp, put the tail in the next node, and put the temp into the tail, like a triangle.

```
                        temp
                       /    ^
                      /      \
                     V        \
                   tail  -- next
```

I attempted to rewrite your code, but was confused as to if start is you're root node, and if not, what is you're root node. If it is, it should be only used once, and that is declaring you're tail node.

Good luck, hope I helped,

Stefano